# Find maxima of function.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider polynomial distribution with $\{p_{1} \dots p_{n}\}$ , such as $p_{1}+\dots p_{n} = 1$.

As we know $\mathbb{P}(A_{k_{1} \dots k_n}) = C_{n}(k_{1} \dots  k_{n}) p_{1}^{k_{1}} \dots p_{n}^{k_{n}}$

How can we get $(k_{1} \dots k_{n})$ , when probability is maximum ?

I thought about some Pascal's triangle but what about $p_{i}$ ? It looks like Markov's chain , but I don't know how to step it. Any hints?

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question: Probability is high, when $k_1=np_1,\ldots,k_n=np_n$. I also guess we have $k_1+\ldots+k_n=n$ and I suggest to use $(k_1,\ldots,k_r)$ instead of $(k_1,\ldots,k_n)$.

Comment: @Fakemistake answer in my book is : $p_{i}n \le k_{i} \le (n+r-1)p_{i}$ but how can we get both bounds ?